# How to use WPF Window in Unit Test Project

Tags: wpf, unit-testing

I would like to use WPF window in Unit Test Project.

but I can't find menu in Add Menu.(Project > Mouse Right Click > Add)
(Windows Form is exist...)

How to make wpf window in unit test project?

Comment: Why do you need WPF Window in unit testing project? Are you trying to  test the UI?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I would like to verify drawing function. I make drawing function using some points. I would like to verify drawing result using wpf window..

Comment: No, You shouldn't test the UI that way. Look at UI automation. @BradleyUffner has a answer for you.

Answer (score 2):

Typically the UI isn't tested using Unit Testing.  You should look in to [Coded UI Testing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff977233.aspx), as that is exactly what it was designed to test.